# React/Typescript/Redux Tool Kit work flow for Category component

Tags: beginner, react.js, typescript, redux

I'm quite new to React hooks/Typescript/Redux. I'm building a mock e-Commerce website for my portfolio. I've got a component (Category) working and rendering data with no issues, it follows the below steps

1. gets data from Redux RTK API slice
2. filters the data depending on the URL
3. renders

After initial load, other filters (price, rating, wine variety) and sorting (A-Z, price low to high, on sale) can be applied, you can all so change the number of items per page, it has paging as well.

I was hoping someone with either React/Typescript/Redux knowledge could have a quick look at my code, pick out any obvious issues, bad practices, suggest changes/improvements etc? Be greatly appreciated

```
const Category = () => {
  // ** Work flow **
  // Get data (useGetWinesQuery - Array of objects) from Redux API slice
  // Initial filter: filter the data (categoryPageData function) depending what URL I come into the component with. eg: http://localhost:5000/red - red wines
  // Check to see if any filters or sorting has been applied
  // I create an array depending on how many items per page is selected which is then rendered

  const { data } = useGetWinesQuery();
  const [sortName, setSortName] = useState<string>("");
  const [filters, setFilters] = useState<FilterProps>(filterSettings);
  const [paging, setPaging] = useState<PagingProps>(pagingSettings);
  const [mobileView, setMobileView] =
    useState<MobileViewProps>(mobileViewSettings);
  const { category: urlCategory, variety: urlVariety } = useParams();
  const isMobileView: boolean = useMobileView(MAX_MOBILE_WIDTH);
  const dataRef = useRef<DataProps[]>([]);
  const headerRef = useRef<string>("");

  useEffect(() => {
    setMobileView({ filters: !isMobileView, items: true });
  }, [isMobileView]);

  useEffect(() => {
    // reset page if URl changes
    setSortName("");
    setFilters({});
    dataRef.current = [];
    headerRef.current = "";
  }, [urlCategory, urlVariety]);

  const currentData = useMemo(() => {
    setPaging(pagingSettings);
    let arr = [...dataRef.current];
    if (arr.length) {
      if (Object.keys(filters).length) {
        arr = filterCategoryPageData(arr, filters);
      }
      if (sortName) {
        arr = sortCategoryPageData(arr, sortName);
      }
    }
    return arr;
  }, [filters, sortName]);

  if (data && Array.isArray(data)) {
    if (dataRef.current.length === 0 && urlCategory) {
      const [arr, header] = categoryPageData(data, urlCategory, urlVariety);
      dataRef.current = arr as DataProps[];
      headerRef.current = header as string;
    }

    const pagedData = currentData.slice(
      (paging.page - 1) * paging.pageSize,
      paging.page * paging.pageSize
    );

    const updateFilters = (filter: object) =>
      setFilters({ ...filters, ...filter });

    const removeFilters = (val: string) => {
      if (val === "all") {
        setFilters({});
      } else {
        delete filters[val as keyof FilterProps];
        setFilters({ ...filters });
      }
    };

    const updatePaging = ({ page, pageSize }: PagingProps) => {
      window.scrollTo(0, 0);
      setPaging({ page, pageSize });
    };

    const togglePageItems = () => {
      // either show filters or items on small screen
      const { filters, items } = mobileView;
      setMobileView({ filters: !filters, items: !items });
    };

    return (
      <article>
        <section className={styles.categoryBlurb}>
          <Blurb
            urlCategory={urlCategory}
            urlVariety={urlVariety}
            header={headerRef.current}
          />
        </section>
        {isMobileView && (
          <div className={styles.smlScreen}>
            <Button css="filters" onClick={togglePageItems}>
              {mobileView.filters ? (
                <span className={styles.close}>X</span>
              ) : (
                "Filters"
              )}
            </Button>
          </div>
        )}
        <div className={styles.category}>
          {mobileView.filters && (
            <FilterList
              updateFilters={updateFilters}
              filters={filters}
              currentData={currentData}
            />
          )}
          {mobileView.items && (
            <section className={styles.categoryItems}>
              <div className={styles.detailsCont}>
                <Pills filters={filters} removeFilters={removeFilters} />
                <span className={styles.results}>
                  ({currentData.length}) Available
                </span>
                <div className={styles.sort}>Sort:</div>
                <Sort sortName={sortName} setSortName={setSortName} />
              </div>
              {currentData.length > 0 ? (
                <>
                  <ProductList arr={pagedData} />
                  <div className={styles.categoryFooter}>
                    <div className={styles.pageNumCont}>
                      <PageNumber
                        currentData={currentData}
                        paging={paging}
                        updatePaging={updatePaging}
                      />
                    </div>
                    <div className={styles.resultsPPCont}>
                      <div className={styles.resultsPP}>Results per page:</div>
                      <div className={styles.resultsPPBtns}>
                        <ResultsPP
                          paging={paging}
                          updatePaging={updatePaging}
                        />
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </>
              ) : (
                <div className={styles.noResults}>
                  Sorry, no results:
                  <br />
                  <Link to="/" className={styles.link}>
                    Back to homepage
                  </Link>
                </div>
              )}
            </section>
          )}
        </div>
      </article>
    );
  }
  return null;
};
export default Category;
```